# what is the recommended way to obtain azure go sdk http status code?

Tags: go, azure-sdk

I am using [azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go) for go to manage my resources.  I have a general question for retry policy.
E.g. Say I am going to get a network security group and update the security rules inside it.

```
client := getNsgClient();

nsg, err1 := client.Get(ctx, nsgGroup, nsgName,"") // should retry if err1 is 404

update(nsgRules, newRules)

future, err2 = client.createOrUpdate(ctx, resourceGroup, nsgGroup, nsg) // should retry if err2 is 409.
```

Question: How can I extract http status code from azure-sdk errors? Is there a method for that?

Comment: Since Azure Go SDK does not contain a function `getNsgClient`, it's impossible to say what type the `client` variable has and hence what types are the return values of the `client.Get` call. Please update your question.

Comment: But may be [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/search?q=StatusCode) will get your on track right away?